# Is it bad (or even dangerous) to random_shuffle vector of shared_ptrs?

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, shuffle

```
using namespace std;
vector< shared_ptr<MyObject> > objects;

// objects gets filled in by something

random_shuffle(objects.begin(), objects.end());
```

Is this bad or inefficient for any reason? Is there a better way of doing it? (I want my array of smart pointers sorted randomly)

EDIT:
I'm asking because there are going to be a lot of swaps, and since I don't know the implementation behind the scenes I was wondering if it might be possible that:

- lots of reference counts could be going up and down like crazy, impacting performance
- even worse, is there a possibility of cyclic references that could cause memory leaks

Comment: Why would it be bad? You're just re-ordering a container. What are you concerned will happen?

Comment: sorted randomly, you mean just random shuffle?

Comment: a.) it could be inefficient, every time pointers are assigned to each other reference counts go up and down. or b.) perhaps perhaps cyclic references could artificially increase reference count, causing memory leaks. I don't know, that's why I'm asking (I'm not sure what's happening under the hood).

Comment: With C++11, this will move the shared_ptr's, which is efficient. Pre-C++11, this could be a bit more expensive than you might think. But it's hard to imagine a scenario where it was so expensive that you would decide to avoid it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is nothing bad or inefficient in this.

`std::random_shuffle` only swaps the elements of the cointainer in some random way. `std::swap` is specialized for `std::shared_ptr`'s, so it is safe and as efficient as swapping two pairs of raw pointers, without

> lots of reference counts could be going up and down like crazy,
>   impacting performance

Even if no such specialization existed, it would still be safe and efficient, as it would only rely on *moving* shared pointers, not copying them (and moving a `std::shared_ptr` does not affect reference counter).

As for cyclic references, if you had some - they will still be present, if you didn't - `swap` cannot introduce new.

Comment: That assumes the platform has some super-efficient way to swap `shared_ptr`s that doesn't mess with reference counts. As far as I know, this isn't guaranteed without c++11.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I would expect `std::swap` to be specialized for `shared_ptr`'s even in pre-c++11 implementations. And, hey, it's 2015 already.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "`shared_ptr`" ... "isn't guaranteed without c++11" That makes no sense because there is no `std::shared_ptr` in pre-C++11.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Right, so any implementation of `shared_ptr` that you had wouldn't be guaranteed to provide any particular performance characteristics.

Comment: @BaummitAugen it's not `std::shared_ptr`, it's `shared_ptr`. Many libraries (Boost.SmartPtr being an example) have their own implementations, independent from the standard.

Comment: @BaummitAugen it was in Boost and `std::tr1` before C++11, so there's probably code out there that qualifies.

Comment: I think @DavidSchwartz is right, swapping both the pointer and the reference count at the same time is problematic - you can't do it atomically.

Comment: @MarkRansom nothing was said in the question concerning atomicity. With it, things obviously get more complicated.

Comment: I suppose you're right, the standard doesn't make any guarantees about thread safety for `shared_ptr`. I'm more used to COM interface pointers which generally are safe due to atomic increment/decrement.

Comment: It's hard to imagine any situation where the efficiency concerns would be so significant that it would justify doing this some other way. And it's certainly safe and legal. And most likely, it will just swap members of the `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

The requirements for `std::random_shuffle` usage is elements should be ValueSwappable and the container should have a random_access iterator support. `std::shared_ptr`s are ValueSwappable  and std::vector has random access iterators.  So it should be safe and it will not make any change in `std::shared_ptr::use_count()`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ValueSwappable